# jQuery DataTables: how to sort by custom parameter value rather than the content of the cell?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable, datatables

I have a pretty common use case where I show the formatted price in a Price column, eg. "20,000.00". So when I try to sort it, it treats it as a string and doesn't sort well:

- 10.00
- 20,000.00
- 5,000.00

Can I make it so that it would sort by the data- parameter value, which would be non-formatted float number?

And related to this question: how do you disable sorting for the given column? I'm using DataTables 1.9.4.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your first question, you could use the Formatted Numbers plugin available on the DataTables plugin page. I would post the code here, but since they update often, I'll just post the link instead.

http://datatables.net/plug-ins/type-detection

You have a couple of options for disabling sorting on a particular column.  You could take the legacy route and put a line in your init object such as...

```
"aoColumns": [
   null,null,null,{ "bSortable": false },null,null
]
```

Where null is a column you don't want to do anything to, and the bSortable object is the column you want to effect.

Since you are running 1.9+, you can do the following.

```
"aoColumnDefs": [
    { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 4 ] }
],
```

In this example, 4 is the column you want to disable sorting on.  Remember, the first column is 0, so this would technically be the 5th column.

Comment: Not able to add a custom sorting, do you have a sample code? I'm trying to use Formatted Number and when I use sType:"formatted-num", it just disabled the sorting for that column. Any ideas?

Comment: what exactly is between the <td> and </td>.  If there is other HTML in there you will need to use Numbers with HTML type detection plugin.

Comment: @shershams Be sure you included the code from the link before you initialize data tables.  I typically throw all of that into a js file and include it via a script tag just to be sure I am always using it.  After that, it should start working correctly for you.  If you are using Chrome, check the console to see if there are any error messages.  If Firefox, use firebug, and if IE, well, I think it has a console of sorts when you hit F12, but only in newer versions.

Answer (score 3):

Use this page http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting to see all the sorting types you can add.  There are quite a few out there and are easy to use.  Basically you need to include the piece of code that it shows under the show details section of each type.  This code needs to be included after datatables has initialized. Personally since I have quite a few that I use across my site, I have made a separate file called datatables.sorting.js and I include that after I include datatables.  This way I can add as many of the various sorting types as needed.

After you add the code, you can use the aoColumns parameter to tell datatables to apply that sorting method on whichever column you want:

```
$('#myTable').dataTable({
"aoColumns": [
            null,
            null,
            { "sType": "formatted-num" }
        ]
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/davidstetler/5Z8fZ/

I added the code for sorting formatted numbers which you can include like I did, or you can include in a separate file.