# Sorting dataTables columns through a custom sortId

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables

I am using [jQuery DataTables](http://datatables.net/) 1.9.4 to present data. I have new custom types to display in cells and adding a custom sort function for each type would be very tricky and poorly maintenable, because the display format is not easily related to the represented value. For example the display format could be `3 oranges, 4 apples` and the value for sorting would then be `7`.

The best solution I can think of is to provide a `sortId` attribute to each cell, that would be an integer, and cells of a column would be sorted through this `sortId`.

```
before
<td>3 oranges, 4 apples</td>

after
<td sortId="7">3 oranges, 4 apples</td>
```

I searched on the web and it doesn't seem to be a feature of *dataTables*. How could I achieved that?

Notice that the `sortId` doesn't have to be necessarily an attribute of `<td>`, any other hidden solution would be fine, as long as not so many characters would be needed.

---

The [data-sort](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/orthogonal-data.html) attribute is definitely what I was looking for thanks!

I experimented adding this attribute a bit with no luck (both with `data-sort` and `data-order`).

- Do I need to tweak anything in my table to make it work?
- I use a 2012 version of datatable (v1.9.4) was this feature already implemented in this version? a textual search in the file *jquery.dataTable.js*  shows zero match for `data-order` and `data-sort` strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**jQuery DataTables 1.10+**

If you want to use `td` element attributes, there is `data-sort` attribute that defines the value that would be used for sorting of HTML sourced data.

```
<td data-sort="7">3 oranges, 4 apples</td>
```

See [this example](http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html) for more information and demo.

Alternatively, you may use [`columns.render`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) option but that is more suitable for Ajax- or JavaScript-sourced data.

**jQuery DataTables 1.9**

Use [`aoColumnDefs.mRender`](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns#mRender) to produce content for cell when the data is being sorted as shown below:

```
var table = $('#example').dataTable({
    "aoColumnDefs": [{
        "aTargets": [0],
        "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
            if (type === "sort") {
                var numbers = data.match(/\d+/g);

                data = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                    data += Number(numbers[i]);
                }
            }
            return data;
        }
    }]
});
```

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bo2pebq2/1/) for code and demonstration.

Alternative solution for jQuery DataTables 1.9 would be to use hidden element and supply sorting value there. Please note that the values would be compared as strings so add zero-padding to numbers if necessary.

```
 <tr>
     <td><span style="display:none">0007</span> 1 apple, 6 oranges</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td><span style="display:none">0005</span> 3 apples, 2 oranges</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td><span style="display:none">0006</span> 5 apples, 1 orange</td>
 </tr>
```

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bo2pebq2/5/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Orthogonal data would also be a great solution -> https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/orthogonal-data.html ...A column render returning different values according to `type` would work too.

Comment: @davidkonrad, `columns.render` doesn't apply here although I mentioned it in my answer. How do you imagine to parse `3 oranges, 4 apples` and produce `7` with `columns.render`?

Comment: loop through `/^\d+/.match(s)` and sum all numbers found together - ending up in 7 or whatever there is found inside the string.

Comment: Thanks Gyrocode.com data-sort is definitely what I needed. Yet I cannot make it work easily, see my extra-questions

Comment: @PatrickfromNDependteam, this feature is available in jQuery DataTables 1.10+ only, suggestion by davidkonrad would work better then. Let me update my answer for DataTables 1.9.

Comment: @davidkonrad, it appears OP uses 1.9 and rendering is the only option here, thanks for the tip used it for alternative solution.

Comment: would this trick work in my case? http://stackoverflow.com/a/20684151/27194       the orange/apple sample I show is simplistic and doesn't reflect the complexity of my situation where unfortunatly the @davidkonrad solution is not an option

Comment: @PatrickfromNDependteam, this trick with comments didn't work for me but when I replaced comments with hidden elements, it worked, see https://jsfiddle.net/bo2pebq2/4/