# Sort column in datatable using custom html attribute with ASP.NET Core

Tags: javascript, datatable, .net-core

I have a table with three columns: `Id`, `Name` and `Size`

In MVC view I have like:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Size</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.Id
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span data-sort="@item.SizeVal">
                        @item.Size
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The `Size` looks like: `15 MB` or `1.25 GB` etc.

And `SizeVal` from `data-sort` attribute is a number converted from MB, GB to Bytes.

In javascript, I initialise [datatable](https://datatables.net/) object

```
var $fileTable = $(".table");

var dtable = $fileTable.DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [
        { "type": "any-number", targets: 2 }
    ],
    order: [[2, "desc"]],
    //responsive: true,
    stateSave: true,
    pageLength: 25
});
```

I want when sort Size column, should take in consideration value from `data-sort` attribute.

I tried with

```
"columnDefs": [
   { "type": "any-number", targets: 2 }
],
```

but not sort well.

How to achieve this ?

Comment: [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286162/custom-sorting-on-values-in-a-data-sort-attribute-with-jquery-datatables)   [Link2](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datatables read the `data-sort` that is in the current `td`.

So rather than putting it in the span you need to put it in the `td` as shown in the HTML part here [here](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html)

```
<td data-sort="@item.SizeVal">
    @item.Size
</td>
```

Please also read the [documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data#HTML-5) explaining it.

Comment: @SnakeEyes I updated the code then to be as correct as possible.