# Datatable sort filter by column

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4, datatable

In one of the columns datatable there is data contains day. I want to sort column but what happens is like the image below. maybe because the system reads as a string because there is a letter 'D' in the column.

How do I make the data read as numbers so it can be sorted without having to remove the 'D'?
[image]

**Edit :**

this is a snippet of the function script for datatable

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#datatable_fix').DataTable({
             "pagingType": "full_numbers"
          });
     });
```

Comment: Use data-sort to provide a simple. pre-converted numeric value to sort on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286162/custom-sorting-on-values-in-a-data-sort-attribute-with-jquery-datatables

Comment: @freedomn-m  thank you very much, this answer really helped me. Unfortunately this solution only works when the query is sorted according to that column.

Comment: ?  You just said: you can only sort on that column when you sort on that column... ?  What other sorting did you want?

Comment: Another approach is to use DataTables' support for [orthogonal data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data). This allows you to display `209 D` (the text) in the table but use `209` (the number) for sorting. There are examples in the linked documentation - and many answers on Stack Overflow referring to "datatables" and "orthogonal". The column renderer example may be the best for your situation: See `render: function ( data, type, row ) { ... }`